# C - Setting 'popen' subprocess's stdin - Cross Platform

Tags: c

I want to start a subprocess via `popen`. I'm having trouble transferring data to its `stdin`.

Here's the Golang code that helps you understand what I'm trying to achieve in C.

```
subProcess := exec.Command("./command")
subProcess.Stdin = bytes.NewReader([]byte{1, 2, 3}) // create stream from bytes
subProcess.Run()
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute/blob/master/gitbrute.go#L81)

I'm looking for a cross platform solution. `_popen` is available on Windows, but I can't use `fork` or `clone`. As a result, I don't know how to set `stdin` for a subprocess.

My problem is, I can't find a way to do that without `fork`.

Comment: When you use `popen()` with the `”w”` mode, what you write on the file stream goes to the process’s standard input. There isn’t a better cross-platform function unless perhaps you adopt a bigger cross-platform library and port that to your target platforms.

Comment: For Windows, look at the `CreateProcess` API, specifically the `STARTUPINFO` struct: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [_popen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen) and [popen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) ok?

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
#define popen  _popen
#endif
FILE *subprocess_stdin = popen("./command", "w");
fwrite(((char[]){1,2,3}), 1, 3, subprocess_stdin);
```